# My simple client crash everytime it tries to connect to my python socket server

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, serversocket

My client crash everytime it tries to connect to my python socket server. I dont know why but but my server seams to start up fine then when i start up my client it establishes a connection to the server but it crash direct. Im doing almost as what they say in [py socket docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socket.html) so im wondering if i have missed something or just staring blindly on something easy. Could any one help pls im using python3.4.

server.py

```
import socket 

host = ''
port = 1010

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.bind((host, port)) 
s.listen(1) 
conn, addr = s.accept() 
print ("Connection from", addr) 
while True: 
    databytes = conn.recv(1024)
    if not databytes: break
    print("Recieved: "+(databytes.decode('utf-8')))
    response = input("Reply: ") 
    if response == "exit": 
        break
    conn.sendall(response.encode('utf-8')) 
conn.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket 

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 1010 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.connect((host, port)) 
print("Connected to "+(host)+" on port "+str(port)) 
initialMessage = input("Send: ") 
s.sendall(initialMessage.encode('utf-8'))  

while True: 
 data = s.recv(1024) 
 print("Recieved: "+(data.decode('utf-8')))
 response = input("Reply: ") 
 if response == "exit": 
     break
 s.sendall(response.encode('utf-8')) 
s.close()
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting when the client crashes?

Comment: The server says that it got a Connection from <'127.0.0.1' , 60326> the client says nothing in command promp in the python shell it says Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\client.py", line 9, in <module>
    initialMessage = raw_input("Send: ")
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your server/client programs.

1. You server has two `accept()` calls, before the while loop and inside the while loop , this causes the server to actually wait for two connections before it can start receiving any messages from any client.
2. The `socket.sendall()` function takes in `bytes` not string , so you need to encode the string using some suitable encoding to convert it to bytes , before sending the data . Also , the function - `socket.recv()` - returns bytes . So you need to decode the bytes data (using the same encoding you used to encode when sending) , so that you can get the correct string back and it can be printed. A suitable encoding can be - `utf-8` - but you can use any encoding of you choice.

An example of encoding a string and using `sendall()` func -

```
s.sendall(response.encode('utf-8'))
```

an example of decoding the string when receiving the data -

```
databytes = conn.recv(1024)
if not databytes: break
data = databytes.decode('utf-8')
```

You do not neccessarily need to store the decoded value in another variable, you can also directly call the `.decode('utf-8')` function when printing the data like - `print("Recieved: "+(data.decode('utf-8')))` .

Comment: Yes i know that i got 2 accept() strangly with out the one in the loop the server crash when i connect to it with the client.

Comment: There are two issues that i described, please check it

Comment: Ok i changed the code and updated it in my original question now things starting to work but i got one new error server side                                                                                                             print("Recieved: "+(data.decode('utf-8')))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: You do not need to double decode, only one of them should be enough - `data = databytes.decode('utf-8')
    print("Recieved: "+(data.decode('utf-8')))`

Only decode, either in first line or second

Comment: I hade to do a lot of tinkering i found a lot of errors in my code that i hade to straighten out but now it works thanks for the help. Ps i have updated the code in the original question.